# How to update vue component data item from vuex store based on condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to update "slotParams" property with vuex store getter only when condition is true. In code below after first true check vue starts observing "this.$store.getters.ENCOUNTER.params" and updating "slotParams" regardless of whether the condition is true or false.

```js
props: {
  name: { required: true }
},
data(){
  return {
    slotParams: {}
  }
},
computed: {
  isActive() {
    const encounter = this.$store.getters.ENCOUNTER
    if(encounter.name === this.name){
      this.slotParams = encounter.params
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
},
```

The example of what I want is below. I need to break reactivity and control updating it manually.

```js
props: {
  name: { required: true }
},
data(){
  return {
    slotParams: {}
  }
},
computed: {
  isActive() {
    const encounter = this.$store.getters.ENCOUNTER
    if(encounter.name === this.name){
      this.slotParams = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(encounter.params) )
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
},
```

**Is there a way to do it in a proper way?**

Answer (score 0):

If store data changes, and this is done reactively, you could just use mapGetters like below, also don't set values directly with computed values, what you are doing in `isActive` is more of a method, setting values with computed properties can often lead to endless loops of change.

If I understood you correctly, I would try out the below.

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
   props: {
      name: {
         type: String,
         required: true
      }
   },

   data() {
      return {
         slotParams: {}
      }
   },

   computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
         encounter: 'whatever-your-path-is/encounter'
      });,

      isActive() {
         return this.encounter.name === this.name;
      }
   },

   watch: {
      encounter: {
         deep: true,
         handler() {
            // This might be where you want to check conditional for this.isActive
            this.slotParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.encounter.params));

            /*
               if (this.isActive) {
                  this.slotParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.encounter.params));
               }
            */
         }
      }
   }
}
```